# Using python to access opendap gridded data

Tags: python, grid, wget, opendap

I am trying to access data from this url:
OPeNDAP/DODS Data URL:  http://climatedata.ibs.re.kr:9090/dods/public-data/pcesm-3ma/pcesm-3ma

I have tried using a GNU wget module and also using the following python: code

```
import netCDF4
url = "http://climatedata.ibs.re.kr:9090/dods/public-data/pcesm-3ma/pcesm-3ma"
dataset = netCDF4.Dataset("http://climatedata.ibs.re.kr:9090/dods/public-data/pcesm-3ma/pcesm-3ma"
```

Both attempts to get this dataset has resulted in HTTP server timing out.

This is gridded data from CESM2 global circulation model which is transient simulation of the last 784,000 years. I am interested in the "ts" - surface temperature variable only.

I wanted to see if anyone else struggles to access this data, or if it is something I am doing wrong. The group that developed the model does have a sample code for access the model through MATLAB but I have no experience in this language and would like to access the data through Python if possible.